# How to overwrite file fortran?

Tags: fortran, overwrite

I have a problem when running Fortran program on windows (the problem is gone in linux) that i can't overwrite existing file, he give me an error after running the code

> Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

but if i'm deleting the file everything work just fine.  That is very annoying problem because during the code testing i'm running it a lot of times, any ideas?

Comment: This almost certainly has nothing to do with overwriting the file, but is rather a bug in your code. While developing you did compile with all the run time checks enabled? For instance with gfortran this means -fcheck=all

Comment: I guess you might actually have a bug elsewhere than the file-related part. This bug may be related to memory access, like an index overruns the bounds of an array. The program might be tolerating the bug as much as possible, but the file opening might be triggering a catastrophe. How about compiling the program with some options that checks array bounds, etc. (e.g. `-check all` for intel fortran)?

Comment: Download valgrind and walk through the program. Pay attention to the values of your variables and which parts of your arrays are being accessed: you messed up allocation or access somewhere. Make sure you compile your program using debug symbols before you do so.